# Importing a self invoking function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have created a particular effect and wrapped it into a self-invoking function in myEffect.js file,

```
(function () {
    // yada yada...
}());
```

Is it possible to then use the es6 way of importing to import this into my main file so that it will run as it is? Reason I'm doing this is my main js file has other misc stuff and this effect is pretty long in itself and I'm hoping to be able to split things up.

Comment: You need to `export` something to `import`. You can assign this function to a variable and export it.

Comment: Is something like `export default (function () { /* code code */ }())` possible ?

Comment: yes it's possible.
This is much cleaner `export default () => console.log('a');`

Comment: for executing you can do like this also.

`
const a = () => {
 // some code
}

export default a();
`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The effect will run when the module is evaluated, which happens when it is imported at least once in some other module.

You don't need an IIFE at all, ES6 modules already provide their own scope.

You don't need to export anything, as all your module is supposed to do is execute the side effect. It does not have a result value. (Which could be considered a design flaw, but let's not discuss that).

All you need to do is

```
// myEffect.js
… // yada yada
```

```
// main.js
import 'myEffect.js';
```

Comment: Oh... I didn't know you can simply import like that... Ha... All the tutorials and instructions out there are export and import, name, un-named, etc... So I can just import the js and let it run? That'll be awesome. Haha.

Comment: Yes, it's that simple :-)

Comment: We're using a monorepo (lerna) and can't work out how to get this happening without an export. Any advice for that? (probably I'm just doing it wrong)

Comment: @JarrodMcGuire You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you can share your code and setup, but I doubt it has to do with a monorepo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import the file as such and execute the function wherever you want 
for example

```
module.exports=(function () {
    // yada yada...
}());

var effect = require('./effect.js)
```

now using effect you can access those in the file.